# Using which Azure API my software can identify if it's running on Azure infrastructure and not elswhere

Tags: azure

We are going to create Virtual Machine Image on Azure Marketplace. This VM Image will have our software, which has default feature and advanced feature. We don't want to ship/install software with advanced feature.

We want to write a service using Azure API, which will first check VM created using this Machine Image or software is running on Azure only and not else where before enabling the advanced feature.

I've found answers to similar questions but all were for WebService. I've also gone through API references provided on Docs section but there too I couldn't find any api solving my purpose so raising this question.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to attempt the instance metadata service query. You can find more information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: There is one point where this approach can be faked and software can be used with full features without proper licensing/usage tracking. If someone copies the software (or VHD) and runs it in fake Azure environment(where 169.254.169.254 address is assigned to fake machine), validation with this approach will be successful .                                                                                              Do we have any other way of securely validating, software is running on genuine Azure env?

Comment: You might be able to try using [Managed Service Identity](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/04/13/demystifying-managed-service-identities-on-azure/) to set up something where you software can only access a certain thing (I'm not sure what that "thing" should be) if it has a Managed Service Identity.  But simple versions of that are probably no better than instance metadata. Making it robust against deliberate attack  would require some careful thought.